# Clear/Remove Jquery Comobobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I am using this Jquery Comboxbox

```
/*!
 * Combobox Plugin for jQuery, version 0.5.0
 *
 * Copyright 2012, Dell Sala
 * http://dellsala.com/
 * https://github.com/dellsala/Combo-Box-jQuery-Plugin
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2012-01-15
 */
```

I can bind data to it:

```
$('#' + selectorId).combobox(data);
```

*where **data** is an array.*

But I am **not able to remove/clear**  once data is bound. It keeps on adding another combobox over previous combobox on adding. I have tried this

```
$('#' + selectorId).empty();
```

but its not working.

**HTML GENERATED**

```
   <span class="combobox" style="position:relative; display:-moz-inline-box; display:inline-         block;">
   <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DropoffLocation$txtDropoffAMeetPoint" type="text" id="txtDropoffAMeetPoint" class="txt txtDropoffAMeetPoint combo_textbox" onblur="return _setEditRideStopMeetPointService(false, true, this);" style="margin: 0px 32px 0px 0px;">
   <a href="#" class="combobox_button" style="position:absolute; height:32px; width:32px; top:0; left:351px;"><div class="combobox_arrow"></div></a>
   <div class="combobox_selector" style="display:none; width:351px; position:absolute; left: 0; top: 32px;">
        <ul>
                <li>Baggage Claim Meet</li>
                <li>Curbside - Wait in Holding</li>
                <li>Meet Outside Customs</li>
                <li></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
    </span>
```

where input with name ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DropoffLocation$txtDropoffAMeetPoint is the textbox whom it is binded. It is enclosed by span tag on binding.

Comment: plz show the html generated by this combobox..

Comment: as far as i understand combobox working..it is appending a div with class `combobox_selector` .. just try to clear this div `$('.combobox_selector').empty()`

Comment: you have tried my comment????

Comment: @Kartikeya Yes I have already mentioned it in question I tried it as my first attempt

Comment: instead of `$('#' + selectorId).empty();` try `$('.combobox_selector').empty()`

Comment: @Kartikeya Ok as you say give me few minute i will be back with answer

Comment: try my answer below..it will work...

Comment: @Kartikeya Its not working combobox not able to add it again

Answer (score 1):

Once your combobox is filled with data in order to remove/clear previous data try this :-

```
jQuery.combobox.instances[0].setSelectOptions(newdata);// where 'newdata' is an array
```

Comment: I have many comobobox how can i know which instance I need to modify

Comment: @SaurabhSharma..well as far i understand this plugin this answer will work...and if you have many combobox instances then just count the instances starting from 0 and then modify that combobox data as shown in answer.

Comment: No sir, I am keeping this on hold